# How to start Spyder IDE on Windows

Tags: python, pip, spyder

I downloaded spyder using the

`pip install spyder`

in my windows 10 32-bit operating system, but i dont see any desktop icons or exe files to start running the IDE. I downloaded spyder 3, any my python is 3.6.
I even tried creating a shortcut of spyder.exe from the Python3.6/Scripts folder, but it won't open.

Comment: try `spyder` in the terminal.

Comment: already tried that

Comment: Its better if you install `anaconda` as it comes with all builtin packages and its very easy to use. It installs python also you don't need to do it separately.

Comment: (*Spyder developer here*) Did you install `pyqt5` after installing Spyder? Look, pip installations are for *experts* only. So, if you don't have a clear understanding of Spyder dependencies, please install Anaconda instead.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba: the dependency is installed automatically. As can be seen in the answer, it is a typo in the command

Answer (score 36):

The name of the spyder executable was changed to spyder3.exe in python version 3.
I install pyqt5 and spyder via pip and was able to launch spyder3. I first tried without installing pyqt5 and nothing happened. Once I installed pyqt5, then spyder 3 opened.

Try the following from a windows cmd.exe prompt:

```
    C:\Users\..>pip install pyqt5
    C:\Users\..>pip install spyder
    C:\Users\..>spyder3
```

Comment: "pip install --upgrade spyder" will update all Spyder dependencies for you.

Comment: This answer is from 2017. I have just installed Spyder via pip on Python 3.10.7 and nothing I have tried has launched Spyder successfully. Has something changed in newer versions?

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem after setting up my environment on Windows 10. I have Python 3.6.2 x64 installed as my default Python distribution and is in my PATH so I can launch from cmd prompt.

I installed PyQt5 (`pip install pyqt5`) and Spyder (`pip install spyder`) which both installed w/out error and included all of the necessary dependencies.

To launch Spyder, I created a simple Python script (Spyder.py):

```
# Spyder Start Script
from spyder.app import start
start.main()
```

Then I created a Windows batch file (Spyder.bat):

```
@echo off
python c:\<path_to_Spyder_py>\Spyder.py
```

Lastly, I created a shortcut on my desktop which launches Spyder.bat and updated the icon to one I downloaded from the Spyder github project.

Works like a charm for me.

Comment: (*Spyder developer here*) Sorry for the trouble, but we can't install Windows shortcuts with pip.

Comment: I found that running `python -m spyder.app.start` does the same without the need for an extra python script, since `main()` is called automatically `if __name__ == "__main__"`. (Spyder 3.2.8)

Comment: Running "pip install --upgrade spyder" will update all Spyder dependencies for you.

Answer (score 13):

Try these commands in  order

```
pip3 install spyder
spyder3
```

Answer (score 10):

Try the command `spyder3`
If you check the scripts folder you'll find spyder3.exe

Answer (score 7):

As stated in the [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/spyder/installation.html#installing-on-windows-vista-7-8-10) of Spyder, you need to install `PyQt5` first.

Open a Command Prompt as Administrator, then run:

```
pip install pyqt5
pip install spyder
```

Then you can find the `spyder3.exe` in the Python3.6/Scripts folder. You can also make a shortcut to it. No need for Anaconda.

Answer (score 6):

## method 1:

```
spyder3
```

## method 2:

```
python -c "from spyder.app import start; start.main()"
```

## method 3:

```
python -m spyder.app.start
```

Answer (score 5):

Open a command prompt. Enter the command `spyder`. Does anything appear? If an exception is preventing it from opening, you would be able to see the reason here. If the command is not found, update your environment variables to point to the Python3.6/Scripts folder, and run `spyder` again (in a new cmd prompt).

Comment: spyder is not recognizable as an internal or externam command

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Anaconda execute the following commands and your life will be saved!

```
conda update qt pyqt
conda update spyder
```

Answer (score 3):

In case if you want the desktop icon

In desktop, create a new shortcut, in Location paste this

`%comspec% /k spyder3`

then type the name Spyder,

Now you may have Desktop Icon for opening **Spyder**

Answer (score 1):

After `pip install spyder` give this command

```
pip install --upgrade spyder
```

This command will update all Spyder dependencies.

Now in command prompt(cmd) navigate to the scripts folder in your python directory. In my system the path is C:\Users\win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts so i use the following command in command prompt.

```
cd C:\Users\win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts
```

once you are inside scripts directory type spyder3 and press enter and spyder ide starts.

```
C:\Users\win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts>spyder3
```

Answer (score 1):

on windows,

1. `pip install --upgrade spyder`
2. in powershell, start python shell, by typing **python**

   ```
   from spyder.app import start
   start.main()
   ```

That't it.

Comment: I'm unable to start it on Windows; I'm getting the following: https://i.imgur.com/2lmMEGx.png.  If I just type "spyder3" into PowerShell, I get the loading wheel for a second and then nothing happens.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Install Ananconda packages and within that launch spyder 3 for first time. Then by second time you just click on spyder under anaconda in all programs.