# Cannot install Spyder or Jupyter over pip3 macOS

Tags: python, pip, spyder

I have tried to install Spyder and Jupyter notebook using Terminal on my macOs (Mojave) but I am keep getting error:

```
/usr/local/bin/pip3: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9: no such file or directory
```

I have installed Python 3.8.4 and it works on my MacBook but not on my desktop.
I have tried to define a path in my bash file but without a success.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when Python is not installed properly this happens.

In Mac, open a `terminal` and try the following commands

1. `which python`
2. `which python3`

This commands will check for python and let you know the path where Python2 and Python3 are present in the system.

For me, I got one output as `/usr/bin/python` which means I have python installed.

Now, I know python is installed and where is it installed.  From here I can install jupyter.

`/usr/bin/python -m pip install -U jupyter`

Syntax is  `<python_locatoin>. -m pip install -U <package_name>`

**Note**: If you are new, one simple way you can check for `Anaconda Python` and using Anaconda Python3 for your Python, Web Developer, ML and all other works. It has UI, to install Jupyter or Spyder and other

Comment: Tried to install Spyder and Jupyter as suggested. I get "requirement already satisfied", but cannot run it from terminal as before. I wanted to avoid Anaconda since one of the package I am using does not work properly.

Comment: For Jupyter, after installing it. Type `jupyter notebook` in the terminal

Comment: For some reason, Jupyter is now working. No luck with Spyder

Comment: Try to explore like this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44956371/how-to-start-spyder-ide-on-windows